# Is this a French uniform, and what is the time period?

Tags: identification, france, uniform

Sorting through French family pictures, papers and glass slides.
Trying to put names to faces.

[image]

The picture below is the same gentleman (on the right) with his brother, who he had just bumped in to on the front.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It would take a better scan to be 100% certain, but it looks like an [Adrian helmet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrian_helmet), with crossed cannons indicating an artillery unit.

> Branch insignia in the form of a grenade for line infantry and
> cavalry, a bugle horn for chasseurs, crossed cannon for artillery, an
> anchor for colonial troops and a crescent for North African units was
> attached to the front.

A nice example can be seen at the [Australian War Memorial](https://www.awm.gov.au/collection/C157562):

[image]

So yes, French, WW1 era, after 1915.